# How to remove the word "Question" in a survey in Service Now?

Tags: service, servicenow, servicenow-rest-api, servicenow-client-scripts, servicenow-hrsd

I am currently developing in Service Now and I face a problem while creating a survey. Everything is just fine with the options what the answers and questions are but the word "Question" always appears above every question (see screenshot). Does somebody know where I can change that?

Kind regards

Link to screenshot: https://ibb.co/5cTMDnr

I took a look in the Survey and Page Designer but couldn't find anything. I expected just to see the word and remove it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the way your questions are designed has the `name` field as Question and the `details` field as Reachability.

The survey designer supports defining both. If you want to remove the word `Question`, you can make change to your survey in the Survey designer and update the name to the content you've put in the details.

Below is an example of screenshots

Before changes as shown in your screenshot as well
[image: Before changes as shown in your screenshot as well]

Configuration to change the question heading and details
[image: Configuration to change the question heading and details]

Preview after updating the question configuration
[image: Preview after updating the question configuration]